# Saving text file in the data folder of an R package

Tags: r, package, roxygen2

I am trying to save a text file in the data folder of a private package I am developing. 
I tried the following:

```
my_text <- “Some text string”
save.RDS(my_text, file = “C/…./package_name/data/mytext.rda”)
```

When I try to build the document, I get the error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded
Calls: suppressPackageStartupMessages ... <Anonymous> -> load_all -> load_data -> unlist -> lapply -> FUN
In addition: Warning message:
file mytext.rda' has magic number 'X'
  Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated 
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

What could I do to save the text?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What about using `R/sysdata.rda` that can be generated with `devtools::use_data(my_text, internal = TRUE)`

Comment: @PoGibas this works very well. If you put it as an answer I can selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way is using `devtools::use_data(my_text, internal = TRUE)` as mentioned by @PoGibas.

Answer (score 0):

Library(readr)

write_rds(x = my_text, path = "C/…./package_name/data/mytext.rda")

try this.